# xhtml / css best practices of naming divs

Tags: css, html, xhtml

Is it valid to name divs like this?

`<div class="frame header">Some content here</div>`

With a space in the name? Then, of course, in the css I would have something like:

```
.frame { display: block; }
.header { background-color: #efefef; }
```

I guess I'm just wondering if you can have a space in the actual markup like I posted and it be XHTML strict? I've checked on the W3C validation, but for some reason, anything I put in there is passing. Sigh...

Comment: This is not the 'name' of the div, but the assignment of two classes, which is of course correct.

Answer (score 2):

ids and classes can't have spaces. If you put a space then you're adding two classes, so W3 is interpreting that as it is and won't throw you an error. Your css is correct.

Comment: The idea was that I would sort of cut down on the amount of css properties in my stylesheet. So, I would use frame as a general class, then use something like header like I did to add another property. I don't know if that makes any sense? Hehe. Hard to explain I guess...

Comment: Yeah, take a look at **animuson** answer. If you want something unique, then use an id. And a class for something that you gonna have in multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The class is not really a 'name' for the element, but a list of classes that apply to it, separated by spaces. If you want that element to have a specific 'name' that pertains only to it, use the `id` attribute. Remember that is has to be completely unique in the document, and also that ID's cannot have spaces.

Something like:

```
<div class="frame" id="header">Some content here</div>
```

```
.frame { display: block; }
#header { background-color: #efefef; }
```

Comment: Yes, ids are unique, but there's nothing wrong with using a unique class, even though and id would be more appropriate.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a ton! I've been doing html for years and years but never really knew if I could do this or not. Never asked. I've seen it done the way I just asked before, but didn't know if it would validate or anything. Anyway, thanks for the interactions! Kinda fun, eh?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is valid.

However, any number of `<div>` elements in an html/xhtml document can have the same class definitions for presentation purposes.

Since the `name` attribute has been replaced with `id` attribute in xhtml, it is always better to have an `ID` attribute to uniquely name and reference a particular element.